# Using Quaternion Coefficients to transform a vector from one reference frame to another

Tags: matrices, complex-geometry, transformation, quaternions

I hope this question is not too trivial, and I welcome any pointers to good resources for this problem. I am not familiar with quaternions and have never had to use them before--all my learning about them has been my reading tonight. But most of the resources I've found haven't been too helpful, and I suspect I'm missing vocabulary that I might need to get to the information I need.

Suppose I have sensor which provides the quaternion coefficients for its relative rotation to some "primary" frame of reference. These coefficients are available in a vector, $\langle w,x,y,z\rangle$, corresponding to the quaternion $w + xi + yj + zk$. I have a second vector, provided by the same sensor, which indicates acceleration, and is provided in the form $\langle X,Y,Z\rangle$. This second vector provides the data from the sensor's frame of reference, **not** with respect to the "primary" frame of reference.

My goal is to transform the acceleration vector to the primary reference frame, so I can find the components of that vector with respect to my primary reference frame. This way I can determine the acceleration in each direction in the primary frame of reference.

From terms I've encountered, and a handful of other posts on similar issues, it seems that I would need to use some sort of rotation matrix, or possibly--since I have the quaternion already--use its inverse to return to the primary frame. But I am unsure of this, and wouldn't know how to do that without a better understanding of the methods involved.

I am hoping someone could point me to clear resources on this sort of problem, or explain the procedure (ideally with a simple example), and would be deeply grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a useful, sufficiently clear document on the subject:

[quaternion-tutorial.pdf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/motib/mathematics/master/quaternions/quaternion-tutorial.pdf)

This source has provided everything I needed.

To summarize the solution, for an acceleration vector **a**, and a quaternion vector **q**, we have:

$$\text{a}' = \text{qaq}^{-1}$$

A quaternion rotation can be undone by simply taking the inverse of the quaternion vector and applying it to the acceleration vector. Such that:

$$\text{a} = \text{q}^{-1}\text{a}'\text{q}$$

For the link I supplied, this is as simple as taking the multiplication on page 16, and adjusting the sign of the elements of the quaternion vector such that $\text{q}_1$ through $\text{q}_3$ are of the opposite sign.

Comment: Contacted the Author, Mordechai (Moti) Ben-Ari, and got a new link for the document.